# What is the Grails Console of Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-boot

I recently started spending more time on Spring Boot and have the started to feel the absence of a shell (similar to Grails console) like application that I can play with the repositories, services etc... Does something like this exist in spring boot?

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123964/how-do-you-use-spring-data-jpa-outside-of-a-spring-container?

Comment: @DegenSharew just did. I think it's talking about accessing repos without sb container. What I want is a GUI like Grails console... Did I miss something from the SO thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently launched the [Spring Context from Groovy](https://github.com/grayshirts/spring-ctx-groovy) project, that gives you access to all beans object within the [Remote Shell](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.6.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-remote-shell.html) plugin using the `repl groovy` interactive console.

Looks like this:

```
$ ssh -p 2000 user@localhost
user@localhost's password:
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::  (v1.4.6.RELEASE) on myhost
> repl groovy
Using repl groovy
> ctx.App.myUserService.findUserByEmail("mrsarm@gmail.com")[0].id
100123
> ctx.App.myUserService.getById(100123).name
Mariano Ruiz
> ctx.App.contactDao.logger.effectiveLevel
INFO
> ctx.App.contactDao.logger.setLevel(ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am sure a lot of people will rely on your project.

Comment: Unfortunately, because this project rely on Remote Shell that was discontinued in Spring Boot 2.0+, my project only works with Spring Boot 1.x projects

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my previous post and later in a comment, you can use the [Spring Context from Groovy](https://github.com/grayshirts/spring-ctx-groovy) tool for a Spring Boot 1.x project, but because changes in the Spring Boot framework, it does not work for Spring Boot 2+ projects, in that case you can use the [jshell-plugin](https://github.com/mrsarm/jshell-plugin) along with [spring-ctx](https://github.com/mrsarm/spring-ctx) (two projects that I also created).

**Quick setup** following the steps [here](https://github.com/mrsarm/jshell-plugin#getting-started) and [here](https://github.com/mrsarm/jshell-plugin#spring-boot-applications):

1. Add the following to your `build.gradle`:

   ```
   plugins {
     id "com.github.mrsarm.jshell.plugin" version "1.1.0"
   }
   ```
2. Add the following dependency to the `dependencies` section:

   ```
   implementation 'com.github.mrsarm:spring-ctx:1.0.0'
   ```
3. Add at the end of the `repositories` section:

   ```
   maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   ```
4. Any Spring Boot application has a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` that is the starting point of the application, with a `public static void main(String[] args)` method, you need to create a `startup.jsh` file at the root of your project calling that method, eg:

   ```java
   com.my.package.MyApplication.main(new String[]{})
   ```

   You can also add the imports of the business classes you are going to play with, as many as you have, otherwise you can import them once the JShell started:

   ```java
   import com.my.package.services.MyUserService
   ```
5. The configuration is done. You can start the `jshell` session executing within a console:

   ```sh
   $ gradle --console plain jshell
   ```

Once the session started you can play with your Spring application, accessing the bean objects from the Spring context as follow:

```
$ gradle --console plain jshell

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

14:43:28.320  INFO com.my.package.MyApplication             : Starting Application on kubu1910 with PID 5225 (/projects/...
14:43:28.323 DEBUG com.my.package.MyApplication             : Running with Spring Boot v2.2.4.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.3.RELEASE
14:43:28.324  INFO com.my.package.MyApplication             : The following profiles are active: ...
14:43:30.229  INFO boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8010 (http)

...
...

14:43:33.729  INFO tuate.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver : Exposing 3 endpoint(s) beneath base path ''
14:43:33.811  INFO boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8010 (http) with context path ''
14:43:33.816  INFO com.my.package.MyApplication             : Started Application in 6.995 seconds (JVM running for 10.524)

> Task :jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.6
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> var myUserService = ctx.App.getBean(MyUserService.class)

jshell> ctx.App.ppjson(myUserService.getByUsername("admin"))
{
  "name" : "Jhon",
  "lastName" : "Due",
  "username" : "admin",
  "age" : null
}
```

**Final advice**: in Windows / Mac you can call the command with the `rlwrap` to make the autocompletion to work, there is a well know issue with Gradle that cause tabs and arrow keys to not work well, so you can call the JShell as follow:

```sh
$ rlwrap gradle --console plain jshell
```

Also worth to note that you can use the Gradle Wrapper (`./gradlew`) from your project if available instead of an installed version of Gradle (`gradle`).